# Screenshot Button stuck while taking screenshot

Tags: android

Whenever i click on takescreenshot button it stuck and and kept on taking screenshots.

**Stop Button**

The function of this button is to stop the thread and stop the code from taking screenshots.

```
Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        StopThread.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                thread.interrupt();
                check=false;
                //textView.setText(TotalShots);
            }
        });
    }
});
th.start();
```

**Take ScreenShot Button**

The function of this button is to start the thread and start taking screenshots.

```
public void screenShot(View view) throws IOException {
        thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                            if (!Thread.interrupted()){

                                while (check)
                                {
                                    captureScreenShot = (Button) findViewById(R.id.capture_screen_shot);
                                    c = Calendar.getInstance();
                                    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
                                    name = simpleDateFormat.format(c.getTime());
                                    mbitmap = getBitmapOFRootView(captureScreenShot);
                                    imageView.setImageBitmap(mbitmap);
                                    try {
                                        createImage(mbitmap);
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }


                                }
                            }

                        }
                    });
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
```

**Click to view [UI of App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3uKF.png)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to start thread or like that you can simple call method on button click. and than set than bitmap inside imageview or whatever you want for use that bitmap.

volatile boolean flag = true;

```
public void run() 
{
while(flag)
    {    
   // Do your task of calling method of screenshot
    try{
        Thread.Sleep(interval);
    } catch(Exception e){

        }

    }
}
```

set flag false when you click the stop button.

```
public Bitmap takeScreenShot(View view) {

// configuramos para que la view almacene la cache en una imagen
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
view.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_LOW);
view.buildDrawingCache();

if(view.getDrawingCache() == null) return null; // Verificamos antes de que no sea null

// utilizamos esa cache, para crear el bitmap que tendra la imagen de la view actual
Bitmap snapshot = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
view.destroyDrawingCache();

return snapshot;
}
```

Comment: I want the code to keep on taking screenshot till stop button is pressed.

Comment: still problem. It doesn't allow me to press stop button.